# Bipartite nonlocal unitary matrix parameterization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am working on some problem involving optimization over nonlocal unitary operations and I have an idea which I want to verify.

The column vectors of a global unitary matrix $U$ make up a set of nonlocal basis $\{ |e_i \rangle \}$. Say if we take the first state $|e_0 \rangle$ and perform on it a pair of local unitaries $U_A^\dagger \otimes U_B^\dagger$ so that it admits the Schmidt decomposition
$$
|\tilde{e}_0 \rangle \equiv U_A^\dagger \otimes U_B^\dagger |e_0 \rangle = \sum_j \sqrt{\lambda_j} |j \rangle^A \otimes |j \rangle^B.
$$
Then, we tailor for it a control gate $V^\dagger$ of the form
$$
V^\dagger = V = |0 \rangle \langle 0|^A \otimes \mathbb{1} + \sum_{i \neq 0} |i \rangle \langle i|^A \otimes (|0 \rangle \langle i| + |i \rangle \langle 0| + \sum_{j \neq 0, i} |j \rangle \langle j|)^B
$$
which we apply to $|\tilde{e}_0 \rangle$. This is able to disentangle it giving the local state
$$
|s_0 \rangle \equiv V^\dagger |\tilde{e}_0 \rangle = \sum_j \sqrt{\lambda_j} |j \rangle^A \otimes |0 \rangle^B.
$$
If such a procedure is used upon the rest of $\{ |e_i \rangle \}$ they would become local as well since a set of orthogonal basis transform synchronously under unitary operation. Now we have a local basis. It can be further transformed into the computational basis by local unitaries $W_A^\dagger \otimes W_B^\dagger$, where we have $(W_A^\dagger \otimes W_B^\dagger) V^\dagger (U_A^\dagger \otimes U_B^\dagger) U = \mathbb{1}$. Naturally,
$$
U = (U_A \otimes U_B) V (W_A \otimes W_B).
$$
Hence, it seems that we only need to parameterize the  two sets of local unitaries to fully characterize any nonlocal unitary matrix, is this true? If not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You can surely find a pair of local unitaries such that $U_A\otimes U_B$ converts $\lvert e_o\rangle$ into Schmidt form, but that pair of unitaries will not in general do the same for the other $\lvert e_k\rangle$ will it?

Comment: @glS I have recently found an article studying Entangled bases with fixed Schmidt number [link](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/48/24/245301). The basis vectors do not even necessarily have the same Schmidt number, so you are right they do not generally transform synchronously.

Comment: right, so it seems you've found the fallacy in your logic? It seems the argument relies on $U_A\otimes U_B$ putting all the $\lvert e_k\rangle$ into Schmidt form, which is not the case.

Comment: @glS Yes indeed, there seems to be no easy way to parameterize a bipartite unitary. Thanks for the insight!